# Why do Samsung Apps not support the Galaxy S?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, samsung-kies

Why is the Samsung Galaxy S i9000 not supported by Kies or Google, I have tried to download apps from the Samsung apps list but I get a warning that the Galaxy is not supported by Kies or Google.

Answer (score 3):

The Galaxy S is fully supported by Kies, and it runs Google's Android OS so I'm not sure what that's all about.

Samsung does not support Samsung Apps on the Galaxy S, however.  They made that choice for some business reason I am sure.  They list supported phones on [this page](http://www.samsungapps.com/about/onPhone.as).

The best way to get apps is through the Android Market, which is already on the Galaxy S.  Samsung Apps has very few apps and they look sub-par to me.

Comment: U r right about Kies, it does see the fone but will not download apps and when I try to use the calendar app on the Galaxy S the Google account says "can't establish reliaable data connection"

Answer (score 2):

Could this be regional? I have an application called Samsung Apps on my phone, and it works just fine. If you have this software on your phone try using it instead of Kies.

Comment: The fone has a function which offers very limited access to Samsung apps. Can you instruct me on getting a broader range of apps within the fone and not Kies?

Comment: There's a lot of content for Samsung's own OS's (Bada) on Kies, not Android. This is why the selection is limited on Galaxy S.

Comment: My "Samsung apps" app didn't want to work without a SIM-card (only through WiFi), although why not? Perhaps, it  from the mobile operator.

Answer (score 2):

*Pulling this out of comments and into an answer, so it's easier to see...*

The Samsung Kies software isn't only used for Samsung's Android based phones (like the Galaxy S) it is also used to manage phones running Samsung's own [Bada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bada_%28operating_system%29) operating system.

The Samsung Apps store in the Kies software (currently) only holds apps for phones running the Bada software, not Android. You can see the [list of supported phones here](http://www.samsungapps.com/about/onPc.as) at the bottom of the page.

Samsung phones, like the Galaxy S series, that are running Android should have a Samsung Apps icon in their application list on the phone itself, you can find the selection of Android compatible Samsung Apps in here. Currently there aren't many apps in there, though they are slowly expanding, one good thing is that (currently) they're all free, and many of them are full versions of apps that you'd have to pay for if you got them through the Android Market.