# Samsung apps cannot be run. Please try again later

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace, samsung-kies

I'm using Kies to connect my 'Samsung Galaxy Ace' in my PC. All the options like Music,Photos,Videos and Podcasts working fine. But when I click on Samsung Apps under Store option, its showing an error "Samsung apps cannot be run. Please try again later". Could you help me to resolve this problem...?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a Samsung Apps icon on your phone? Have you tried using that one?

[image: Samsung Apps icon]

It's been a little while since I've used Kies, but it is used for all of Samsung's phones, not just the Android ones. The Samsung Apps icon in Kies only used to list [Bada compatible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bada) apps, not Android ones, you needed to use the Samsung Apps icon on your phone to get the Android ones.

Edit: Just realised that this question has come up before, for the Galaxy S: [Why do Samsung Apps not support the Galaxy S?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4361/why-do-samsung-apps-not-support-the-galaxy-s) though that question is from a year ago, so things may have changed since then

Answer (score -1):

Try to re-install the Kies on your PC.And try it once again because i had the same problem and i got it back by this way.